# Decoding the x5c certificate chain while processing a server-to-server notification from Apple

Tags: openssl, jwt

I am trying to process a server-to-server notification from Apple’s app store. The following notes detail what I have discovered, and I welcome any correction that is needed.

The notification is received in a JSON packet and the “signedPayload” can be extracted from it. The signedPayload is in the form of a JWT and can therefore be split into the Header, Payload and Signature.

When the Header is base64 decoded it results in another JSON packet which contains two fields: “alg” and “x5c”. The algorithm field has the value ES256 and the x5c field contains a chain of three certificates separated by commas.

The Payload can be base64 decoded and then interpreted according to the information here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/responsebodyv2decodedpayload

That part is simple. However the payload should not be actioned until the signature is verified.

The Signature is kept for later in the process.

Back to the certificate chain. The last certificate in the chain (certificate 3) is Apple’s root certificate AppleRootCA-G3 certificate. This can be downloaded from https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/
The cer file can be converted to a pem file using openssl as follows:

`openssl x509 -inform der -in AppleRootCA-G3.cer -outform pem -out AppleRootCA-G3.pem`

Comparing the pem file with certificate 3 in the chain will confirm that they are identical.

Similarly, the middle certificate in the chain (certificate 2) is Apple’s intermediate certificate AppleWWDRCAG6.cer. Converting it to a pem file will confirm they are identical.

The first certificate in the chain (certificate 1) is the entity certificate.

The root and intermediate certificates can be converted to text using openssl as follows:

`openssl x509 -text -in AppleRootCA-G3.pem`

`openssl x509 -text -in AppleWWDRCAG6.pem`

This will reveal the issuer and subject of each certificate.
I understand that for the certificate chain to be valid, the subject of the root must match the issuer of the intermediate, the subject of the intermediate must match the issuer of the entity and the subject and issuer of the root must be the same.
https://docs.apigee.com/how-to-guides/validating-certificate-chain#splitcertchain

This is the case. So far, so good.

I am not sure what to do from this point onwards. My thinking is that I need to complete the validation of the certificate chain and then somehow calculate a signature which needs to match the Signature which formed part of the signed payload. How should this be done? I am also unclear as to whether I need the shared secret from our Apple developer’s account, and if so how is it used? The encoding algorithm ES256 must also be used somewhere but again I'm not sure where or how.

Comment: (0) using a program like commandline `openssl` is (now) out of scope of SO, and using it for JWT is complicated enough I can't really answer in comments (1) it is _necessary_ that the cert names chain 1.issuer=2.subject etc and root.subject=root.issuer, but that is not _nearly_ sufficient; dozens of other checks are required. If you convert the certs to PEM format (_not_ merely base64) and given you have the trusted root, `openssl verify` can do rfc5280 validation, but with CRLs only if you provide them explicitly and not OCSP at all; I don't know if Apple needs OCSP for its leaf certs.

Comment: (2) finally, `openssl dgst` can verify (and also create) 'traditional' ECDSA signatures, but not the type JWT/JOSE uses; openssl doesn't support unpadded base64url, and it uses DER encoding not the 'plain' aka P1363 or PKCS11/card encoding used by JOSE (and XMLdsig), so that will require other tool(s) in addition like perl, python, or maybe some pretty complicated shell, all of which depend on your environment(s) which you didn't state

Answer (score 0):

The POST from Apple contains a "signedPayload", which is a JWT -- so the job is to validate the JWT signature and extract the payload once you're sufficiently convinced it's really from Apple.

(DISCLAIMER: I am a crypto novice so check me on this if I'm using the wrong terms, etc. throughout)

1. The header of the JWT contains the certificate chain used to sign it, so first you extract these public keys. These are listed in the "x5c" attribute as base64-encoded asn1 byte strings.
2. Then, you want to validate that a) the chain is valid, and b) the chain starts with a well-known key you can trust. The App Store certs are all signed by Apple's root & intermediate keys which you already have. These should be the last two certificates in the chain listed in "x5c".
3. Once you do that, you can decode the JWT by passing the validated signing key to your handy dandy JWT decoding library, which will verify its signature based on the validated key in the header.

This was a little tricky** in python because Apple is using some combination of formats and algorithms that confuses PyJWT. Here's a gist:
https://gist.github.com/taylorhughes/3968575b40dd97f851f35892931ebf3e

** euphemism

Answer (score 0):

** NOT A CRYPTO EXPERT **
I struggled through this for a while because Apple's docs are pretty sparse on how to validate the signed token.

This [Apple Developer video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10040/) was helpful (information regarding verifying signed tokens starts ~11m mark).

I believe Taylor's overall steps are accurate.  Here is sample code of what I ended up implementing using jsonwebtoken and crypto in node:

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const fs = require('fs')
const crypto = require('crypto')

function decodePayload(token){
  // G3 Cert here https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleRootCA-G3.cer
  var apple_G3_cert = fs.readFileSync('./AppleRootCA-G3.cer') // TODO: download cert from apple
  var x509G3 = new crypto.X509Certificate(apple_G3_cert)

  // Decode the token to obtain the headers
  var contents = jwt.decode(token,{complete: true})

  // Create certs from the x5c array
  var leaf_cert = new crypto.X509Certificate(Buffer.from(contents.header.x5c[0],'base64'));
  var int_cert = new crypto.X509Certificate(Buffer.from(contents.header.x5c[1],'base64'));
  var root_cert = new crypto.X509Certificate(Buffer.from(contents.header.x5c[2],'base64'));

  // Validate the certs' issuers
  if(leaf_cert.checkIssued(int_cert) && 
    int_cert.checkIssued(root_cert) &&
    root_cert.checkIssued(x509G3)){

      // Chain is trusted - Verify signature
      try{
        return jwt.verify(token,leaf_cert.publicKey, {algorithms:'ES256'})
      }
      catch{
        return null
      }
  }else{
    return null
  }
}
```